# What is the difference between Android Id and Device Id?

Tags: android

My device id is : 358313044737548

and

My android id is : 4e4c5141b7cb261e

can some one please explain the difference between these two and the purpose of each?

Thanks

Comment: needs to be moved to android stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device ID refers to the serial number — A string created by adb to uniquely identify an emulator/device instance by its console port number. The format of the serial number is -. Here's an example serial number: emulator-5554

[Android ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device.

Comment: jacobson was refering to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId() and it has nothing to do with ADB. DeviceId comes from Radio and is the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.

Comment: I'd recommend you fix your answer based on pcans comment.

Comment: i think the android id can be reset when refactor your android see this https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: ANDROID_ID is related to user and signin key you can check it in the documentation here => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 2):

One thing that they can be used for is to identify app installations, as described in this [developer's blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).